# Can I protect rows in a Google Docs spreadsheet from sorting?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I can sort a Google Docs spreadsheet on any column, but that sorts ALL of the rows. I don't want to sort the rows that contain the column labels. Is there a way to protect them from being sorted?

I tried protecting those rows from changes, but I can't protect rows from myself. I tried sharing the document with a different account and protecting those rows from that account, then working on it from that account, but the spreadsheet froze in the other account as soon as I protected any rows.

Answer (score 7):

You can freeze the row(s) with column headers, using the menu: View > Freeze > 1 row (or another number).

The frozen rows are not included when executing "Sort sheet A-Z" or "Sort sheet Z-A" from the expandable menu next to column names, or when sorting the sheet from "Data" submenu.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this works for people that are viewers. A viewer can sort, and get a "local only" view, but the frozen rows are included, making the view pretty ugly.